# Can't fetch data from Sqlite database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an issue fetching data from the database. In the LogCat, complained as no such column timeinstance. This is the new column I added into the database. Only fetching has the problem but createNewList doesn't have problem with that column. What could be the problem? I posted my whole database class.

```
public class TrackerDBAdapter {

 public static final String KEY_ROWID   = "_id";
 public static final String KEY_IDNUM   = "_idnum";
 public static final String KEY_SIMCARD = "_simcard";
 public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "_description";
 public static final String KEY_MODEL = "_model";
 public static final String KEY_TIMEINSTANCE = "timeinstance";
 private static final String TAG = "TrackerDBAdapter";
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DBTrackerList";
 private static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "TBTrackerList";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 private final Context mCtx;
 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
          "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
          KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
          KEY_IDNUM + "," +
          KEY_SIMCARD + "," +
          KEY_DESCRIPTION + "," +
          KEY_MODEL + "," +
          KEY_TIMEINSTANCE + "," +
          " UNIQUE (" + KEY_IDNUM +"));";

 private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
 private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

 private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

      DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
          super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
      }


      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
       Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
       db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
      }

      @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
       Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
         + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
       db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SQLITE_TABLE);
       onCreate(db);
      }
 }

 public TrackerDBAdapter(Context ctx) {
      this.mCtx = ctx;
 }

 public TrackerDBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
      mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
      mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      return this;
 }

 public void close() {
      if (mDbHelper != null) {
       mDbHelper.close();
      }
 }

 public long createNewList(String idnum, String simnum, 
           String description, String model, String time) {

          ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
          initialValues.put(KEY_IDNUM, idnum);
          initialValues.put(KEY_SIMCARD, simnum);
          initialValues.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);
          initialValues.put(KEY_MODEL, model);
          initialValues.put(KEY_TIMEINSTANCE, time);
          return mDb.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
 }

 public boolean deleteAllTrackerInTheList() {

      int doneDelete = 0;
      doneDelete = mDb.delete(SQLITE_TABLE, null , null);
      Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
      return doneDelete > 0;
 }

 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Cursor fetchListBySimcardNum(String inputText) throws SQLException {
      Log.w(TAG, inputText);
      Cursor mCursor = null;
      if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
       mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
               KEY_IDNUM, KEY_SIMCARD, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_MODEL, KEY_TIMEINSTANCE}, 
         null, null, null, null, null);

      }
      else {
       mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
               KEY_IDNUM, KEY_SIMCARD, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_MODEL, KEY_TIMEINSTANCE}, 
               KEY_SIMCARD + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
         null, null, null, null);
      }
      if (mCursor != null) {
       mCursor.moveToFirst();
      }
      return mCursor;

  }

 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Cursor fetchListByIDNum(String inputText) throws SQLException {
      Log.w(TAG, inputText);
      Cursor mCursor = null;
      if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
       mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
               KEY_IDNUM, KEY_SIMCARD, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_MODEL, KEY_TIMEINSTANCE}, 
         null, null, null, null, null);

      }
      else {
       mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
               KEY_IDNUM, KEY_SIMCARD, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_MODEL, KEY_TIMEINSTANCE}, 
               KEY_IDNUM + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
         null, null, null, null);
      }
      if (mCursor != null) {
       mCursor.moveToFirst();
      }
      return mCursor;

  }

 public Cursor fetchAllTrackerInTheList() {

      Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, 
              KEY_IDNUM, KEY_SIMCARD, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_MODEL, KEY_TIMEINSTANCE}, 
        null, null, null, null, null);

      if (mCursor != null) {
       mCursor.moveToFirst();
      }
      return mCursor;
 }  

 public int getLastInsertedID() {
      int id = 0;
      Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
              KEY_IDNUM, KEY_SIMCARD, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_MODEL, KEY_TIMEINSTANCE}, 
        null, null, null, null, null);

      if (mCursor.moveToLast()) {
          id = mCursor.getInt(0);
      }
      return id;
 }  

 public void insertSomeCountries() {

       createNewList("AFG","Afghanistan","Asia","Southern", "Central Asia");         

 }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database is not updated.
Try remove your app and reinstall it.

Or you can change the version of the database:

```
       private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

Comment: I am using the emulator. How can I do that?

Comment: with emulator youcan uninstall as you do on your phone. GO, into  the Manage Apps of emulator and unistall it.